# react-native/expo app crash once logged on build

Tags: react-native, build, expo, apk

So i recently made a build (.apk) for my app and the authentication works fine. But once I login the app crashes with error:

`appName[65858]: assertion failed: 20C69 18C61: libxpc.dylib + 50260 [056A9371-1C2C-385B-BB06-F099DE20E73A]: 0x7d`

My app runs fine on the simulator, and I can't make anything out of this error log.

Thank you very much for your help and please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, it is difficult to figure out what's happening just from that error. You should definitely try to debug more. You can always run a release build on your simulator using:

```sh
npx react-native run-android --variant=release
```

Maybe this way you will get more insights.

Because you mentioned something about authentication I assume you are making some HTTP calls. Possible issues:

- The API URL. Maybe you forgot to change some localhost endpoint. Make sure the server is accessible and double-check everything related to that.
- You are making API calls over HTTPS. Depending on your config, you may be allowed to make a network request over HTTP in Development, but on a Production build, you definitely need HTTPS.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering!
I am happy to announce that I found the solution.

I ended up using the console application on Mac to debug the emulator and  finally found the error hidden somewhere In the logs. It said "can't find n.length of undefined".

So I ended up changing all the length calls from n.length  to n?.length  . 

If somebody else has this problem and you have a Mac I would recommend you to check out the Console application.